# Python executable looping create frame

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, pyinstaller

It runs perfectly fine in Idle with no error, then I do `pyinstall --onefile -w System-Toolkit.py` and shows no errors when creating the application, however when I try to run it with/without administrator it begins creating the window over and over again, though the window will only actually show up if I close one of them in task manager.

Here is the code:

```
import platform
import psutil
import cpuinfo
import wmi
import selenium
from tkinter import *

class Window(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        Frame.__init__(self, master, bg="#393939")
        self.master = master
        self.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)

        text = Label(self, text="Version (0.0.0)", bg="#393939", fg="#f73030", font=("Helvetica", 12, "bold"))
        text.pack(padx=0,pady=0, anchor="w")

        text = Label(self, text="System Toolkit", bg="#393939", fg="#f73030", font=("Helvetica", 32, "bold"))
        text.pack(padx=12,pady=10)
        
        text = Label(self, text="Operating System: ", bg="#393939", fg="#30F752", font=("Helvetica", 18))
        text.pack(padx=12,pady=10)

        ostype = f"{platform.architecture()}"
        text = Label(self, text="Architecture:   " + str(ostype), bg="#393939", fg="white", font=("Helvetica", 18))
        text.pack(padx=20,pady=10, anchor="w")

        net = f"{platform.node()}"
        text = Label(self, text="Network Name:   " + str(net), bg="#393939", fg="white", font=("Helvetica", 18))
        text.pack(padx=20,pady=10, anchor="w")

        processor = f"{platform.platform()}"
        text = Label(self, text="Version:   " + str(processor), bg="#393939", fg="white", font=("Helvetica", 18))
        text.pack(padx=20,pady=10, anchor="w")

        text = Label(self, text="CPU: ", bg="#393939", fg="#30F752", font=("Helvetica", 18))
        text.pack(padx=12,pady=10)
        
        mycpu = cpuinfo.get_cpu_info()

        text = Label(self, text="Model:   " + mycpu['brand_raw'], bg="#393939", fg="white", font=("Helvetica", 18))
        text.pack(padx=20,pady=10, anchor="w")

        process = f"{platform.processor()}"
        text = Label(self, text="Model Info:   " + str(process), bg="#393939", fg="white", font=("Helvetica", 18))
        text.pack(padx=20,pady=10, anchor="w")

        text = Label(self, text="Clock Speed:   " + mycpu['hz_actual_friendly'], bg="#393939", fg="white", font=("Helvetica", 18))
        text.pack(padx=20,pady=10, anchor="w")


        text = Label(self, text="RAM: ", bg="#393939", fg="#30f752", font=("Helvetica", 18))
        text.pack(padx=12,pady=10)

        ram = f"{psutil.virtual_memory().total / 1024 / 1024 / 1024:.2f}Gb \n"
        text = Label(self, text="Total:   " + str(ram), bg="#393939", fg="white", font=("Helvetica", 18))
        text.pack(padx=20,pady=10, anchor="w")



root = Tk()
app = Window(root)
root.wm_title("System Toolkit - (v0.0.0")
#root.wm_attributes('-transparentcolor', '#ab23ff')
root.geometry("800x600")
root.mainloop()
root.destroy()
```

I tried using an input to keep the window open, however that only gave errors, and have tried moving the `root.destroy()` to end the loop before it repeats.

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable `freeze_support` from the `multiprocessing` module in the python stdlib.

For example:

```
import platform
import psutil
import cpuinfo
import wmi
import selenium
from tkinter import *
from multiprocessing import freeze_support

freeze_support()

class Window(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        Frame.__init__(self, master, bg="#393939")
        self.master = master
        self.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)

        text = Label(self, text="Version (0.0.0)", bg="#393939", fg="#f73030", font=("Helvetica", 12, "bold"))
        text.pack(padx=0,pady=0, anchor="w")

        text = Label(self, text="System Toolkit", bg="#393939", fg="#f73030", font=("Helvetica", 32, "bold"))
        text.pack(padx=12,pady=10)
        
        text = Label(self, text="Operating System: ", bg="#393939", fg="#30F752", font=("Helvetica", 18))
        text.pack(padx=12,pady=10)

        ostype = f"{platform.architecture()}"
        text = Label(self, text="Architecture:   " + str(ostype), bg="#393939", fg="white", font=("Helvetica", 18))
        text.pack(padx=20,pady=10, anchor="w")

        net = f"{platform.node()}"
        text = Label(self, text="Network Name:   " + str(net), bg="#393939", fg="white", font=("Helvetica", 18))
        text.pack(padx=20,pady=10, anchor="w")

        processor = f"{platform.platform()}"
        text = Label(self, text="Version:   " + str(processor), bg="#393939", fg="white", font=("Helvetica", 18))
        text.pack(padx=20,pady=10, anchor="w")

        text = Label(self, text="CPU: ", bg="#393939", fg="#30F752", font=("Helvetica", 18))
        text.pack(padx=12,pady=10)
        
        mycpu = cpuinfo.get_cpu_info()

        text = Label(self, text="Model:   " + mycpu['brand_raw'], bg="#393939", fg="white", font=("Helvetica", 18))
        text.pack(padx=20,pady=10, anchor="w")

        process = f"{platform.processor()}"
        text = Label(self, text="Model Info:   " + str(process), bg="#393939", fg="white", font=("Helvetica", 18))
        text.pack(padx=20,pady=10, anchor="w")

        text = Label(self, text="Clock Speed:   " + mycpu['hz_actual_friendly'], bg="#393939", fg="white", font=("Helvetica", 18))
        text.pack(padx=20,pady=10, anchor="w")


        text = Label(self, text="RAM: ", bg="#393939", fg="#30f752", font=("Helvetica", 18))
        text.pack(padx=12,pady=10)

        ram = f"{psutil.virtual_memory().total / 1024 / 1024 / 1024:.2f}Gb \n"
        text = Label(self, text="Total:   " + str(ram), bg="#393939", fg="white", font=("Helvetica", 18))
        text.pack(padx=20,pady=10, anchor="w")



root = Tk()
app = Window(root)
root.wm_title("System Toolkit - (v0.0.0")
#root.wm_attributes('-transparentcolor', '#ab23ff')
root.geometry("800x600")
root.mainloop()
root.destroy()
```

Then recompile your script and bob's your uncle.

Comment: I didn't know of that function, thank you, will run it as soon as I get the chance

Comment: Apologies, yes it did, thank you very much!